# How to git status (or show) only submodule changes?

Tags: git

```
git status --ignore-submodules=all
```

I am looking for inverse of this, is there a way to print only the submodule changes? like `git status --show-only-submodules`

EDIT:
My script fetch and merge submodule change, then it fetch and merge super project change. now, I need to check if the newly pulled-in super project change includes the SHA update of submodule change, for that I am thinking to do `git show HEAD^ HEAD` in super project, which prints below:

```
--- a/xyz
+++ b/xyz
@@ -1 +1 @@

-Subproject commit f991877822a8fd50b90f53894f2592a852039547
+Subproject commit f57c051f91b0948a5b8947430b516e650b50348e
```

from here, I will take the `+Subproject commit` and go into `xyz` directory, do a `git log -1 --no-merges` and compare the SHAs, if it matches, then I will assume the super change includes the submodule change that has been pulled in.

For this reason, I like to list **only the submodule changes** when I do `git status --some-option` being in the super project. please let me know if there is a better way to do the same.

Answer (score 14):

This should be the proper solution for you:

```
git submodule foreach git status
```

This will traverse all submodules and execute the given command. From [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt):

> `foreach [--recursive] <command>`
>
> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule. The command has access to the variables $name, $path, $sha1
>   and $toplevel: $name is the name of the relevant submodule section in
>   `.gitmodules`, $path is the name of the submodule directory relative to
>   the superproject, $sha1 is the commit as recorded in the superproject,
>   and $toplevel is the absolute path to the top-level of the
>   superproject. Any submodules defined in the superproject but not
>   checked out are ignored by this command. Unless given `--quiet`, foreach
>   prints the name of each submodule before evaluating the command. If
>   `--recursive` is given, submodules are traversed recursively (i.e. the given shell command is evaluated in nested submodules as well). A
>   non-zero return from the command in any submodule causes the
>   processing to terminate. This can be overridden by adding || : to the
>   end of the command.
>
> As an example, the command below will show the path and currently
>   checked out commit for each submodule:
>
> `git submodule foreach 'echo $path $(git rev-parse HEAD)'`

Comment: Thanks, please see my EDIT: section, which I added now. looks like `git submodule foreach 'echo $path $(git log -1 --format=format:%H --no-merges)'` within `foreach`will give me the sha of the change which I pulled in, thanks again.

Comment: It has nothing to do with expected behaviour of git status. `git status` does not list unchanged files, while `git submodule foreach git status` for each submodule, says: `nothing to commit, working tree clean`. I understand why it works this way, but it does not make the situation better.

Answer (score 2):

[`git submodule status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-status--cached--recursive--ltpathgt82308203)

> Show the status of the submodules. This will print the SHA-1 of the
>   currently checked out commit for each submodule, along with the
>   submodule path and the output of git describe for the SHA-1. Each
>   SHA-1 will possibly be prefixed with - if the submodule is not
>   initialized, + if the currently checked out submodule commit does not
>   match the SHA-1 found in the index of the containing repository and U
>   if the submodule has merge conflicts.
>
> If --recursive is specified, this command will recurse into nested
>   submodules, and show their status as well.
>
> If you are only interested in changes of the currently initialized
>   submodules with respect to the commit recorded in the index or the
>   HEAD, git-status and git-diff will provide that information too
>   (and can also report changes to a submodule’s work tree).

Comment: I think OP is interested in the changes made to the working directory of  the submodule; those aren't reported by `git-submodule-status`, as stated in the last paragraph.